# go to page after the page is loaded 

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

okay so on my home page i'm doing a user name and password check and then im using jquery document.location to send you to a logged in page say secure.php.... while this works it sends you to secure.php first and then images start loading ... how can i do it in such a way that it loads the entire page and then send you to secure.php

example : -

```
 $.ajax ({
         url: loginCheck.php,
         type: 'POST',
         data: username + password ,
         success: function (check){
                if(check==1)
                    document.location= /loginpage/secure.php
                else alert(invalid username or pass)

            }
         });
```

Comment: What if I type directly `http://yoursite.com/secure.php` in my browser address bar without ever passing through the first page and providing any username and password? Have you considered this *use-case* of your site?

Comment: it would just roll you back to the homepage

Comment: But 'roll back to the homepage' with JavaScript, or with server-side logic?

Comment: server side in secure.php ....

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I'm replacing my entire question now that I understand what you are trying to do.  In secure.php, put all of your code in a containing div, something like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="contentContainer">
        <!-- content goes here -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Set a style for `#contentContainer` to be hidden:

```
#contentContainer {
    display: none;
}
```

Add a `window.onload` handler to show the div.  Unlike `onready`, `onload` isn't called until all of the content has loaded including images.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#contentContainer").show();
});
```

You may want to do the same thing in reverse to a "loading" div with a message that says "loading...".  Ie, initially display it, and hide it in the onload handler.

**Edit:** You can speed up the loading of the page by pre-loading the images in a hidden div in the previous page.

Home.php

```
<div class="preloader">
    <img src="..." />
    ...
</div>

.preloader {
    display: none;
}
```

Secure.php should load using the cached images.

Comment: okay so ... in the above example say im doing a button click function would that do into the $(window).load(function()) ??

Comment: okay so i dont think i made myself clear ... im trying to defer secure.php from showing before it has loaded all its contents nothing to do with the homepage

Comment: @Aggiephoenix - Okay, I've replaced my entire answer.  This makes a little more sense now.

Comment: okay looks like i have made things worse .... My login page has the javascript code similar to the one above that checks if the username and password are correct from a database with an ajax call .. when that gets done and if the username and pass are correct it redirects you to the content page which has images .so with my code above it sends you to the content page first and then takes time to load images ... what i would like to know is that if there is a way to have all the contents in the content page ready beforehand and then redirect you to that page

Comment: @Aggiephoenix - Load the images in a hidden div on the home page.  When the secure page loads, it should use the cached images.

Comment: take for example fbook ... when you use your login and password and click login by the the it takes you to the inside page all your content is ready for viewing including images and all ..hope this helps u a bit

Answer (score 0):

...this strikes me as highly unsecure, but oh well.

Unless you build a metaframework in jQuery where all page loads are performed in a "shell" and then displayed only when ready to render, the answer is, I'm pretty sure, you can't.

Pages have a definite life cycle.  jQuery and AJAX kinda blur the line a bit, but a page load is a singular event that controls the scripts.  Loading the page would make the script you were using to load the page go away.

Comment: what part do u think is unsecure?

Comment: The ajax call to the login checker has the user name and password going as a single string.  That's pretty much the same as not having a password, just a weird username.  It also prevents best practices for storing passwords with salted hashes.  So Joe with a password of Pass and Joe Pass with no password are the same person?  Security-wise, this does not sound very robust.

Comment: isnt it happening behind the scene though ? how can rectify it ?

Comment: I'd send them as discrete values, and store them in your repository separately... preferably the password as a salted hash.  When you want to authenticate a username and password, get the salt from the repository with the provided username, hash the password using the salt, and compare to the stored value.  If it matches, good to go!  If not... well shooting them is probably a little severe, but you can get creative.  :)

Comment: oh im using hashed values in login check + my own 64bit encoding to the hash